# Solver cannot find any eigenvalues for linear buckling analysis [COMSOL]

Tags: finite-element-method, buckling

I am trying to do a simple linear buckling analysis, where one end is fixed and the opposing end has a prescribed displacement of -0.1m in the x-direction that compresses the structure. Solver cant find any eigenvalues it seems. Any ideas what I could try to fix this and get those precious buckling modes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about COMSOL, but if there are no loads that can *change* in the model, I'm not surprised it can't figure out what you want to do. If you just want to calculate the pre-stressed vibration modes of the structure, that should be possible as a nonlinear stress analysis + normal modes analysis. If you really want to find the buckling load, try creating a constraint to make the "prescribed displacement" surface planar (so the structure can't deform in ways you don't want) and then apply a *load* to it.  You can then convert the buckling load back to a displacement if you want.

Comment: Thank you @alephzero. By making the prescribed displacement surface planar, do you mean apply it to not just the blue highlighted area as I did, but entire red face? As seen in this picture:   https://imgur.com/a/R0reGfM