# How is a linear buckling test supposed to look like?

Tags: buckling

If I had a cube like object; would this be a good way to set up a linear buckling analysis?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqphm.jpg

And no other forces or boundary conditions

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you think the test to be set up, with what parameters and the analysis result you are expecting?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. You could setup a linear buckling analysis however the critical loads are way higher (for most engineering materials) that the compressive stresses.

Comment: The title says "test" (which implies testing a physical object) and the question says "analysis". Which is it? Also, is this a the same structure as https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44793/solver-cannot-find-any-eigenvalues-for-linear-buckling-analysis-comsol which has a better pictures than your sketch of a cube, and suggests the size of the object is a 2-meter cube..

Comment: We sure get a lot of questions on buckling.  Is this something being taught lately?  Or is it an indication that it's not a well-understood phenomenon? (it isn't by me, for sure)